# How can a method contain only a NotImplementedException and still run without throwing?

Tags: c#, reflection, notimplementedexception

If I check in Reflector for [`FieldInfo.SetValueDirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvaluedirect.aspx) it looks as follows:

C#, .NET 4.0:

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public virtual void SetValueDirect(TypedReference obj, object value)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(Environment.GetResourceString("NotSupported_AbstractNonCLS"));
}
```

And as IL:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void SetValueDirect(valuetype System.TypedReference obj, object 'value') cil managed
{
    .custom instance void System.CLSCompliantAttribute::.ctor(bool) = { bool(false) }
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldstr "NotSupported_AbstractNonCLS"
    L_0005: call string System.Environment::GetResourceString(string)
    L_000a: newobj instance void System.NotSupportedException::.ctor(string)
    L_000f: throw 
}
```

However, if I run the following code, it *just works*.

```
// test struct:
public struct TestFields
{
    public int MaxValue;
    public Guid SomeGuid;   // req for MakeTypeRef, which doesn't like primitives
}


[Test]
public void SettingFieldThroughSetValueDirect()
{

    TestFields testValue = new TestFields { MaxValue = 1234 };

    FieldInfo info = testValue.GetType().GetField("MaxValue");
    Assert.IsNotNull(info);

    // TestFields.SomeGuid exists as a field
    TypedReference reference = TypedReference.MakeTypedReference(
        testValue, 
        new [] { fields.GetType().GetField("SomeGuid") });

    int value = (int)info.GetValueDirect(reference, );
    info.SetValueDirect(reference, 4096);

    // assert that this actually worked
    Assert.AreEqual(4096, fields.MaxValue);

}
```

No error is thrown. Same is true for [`GetValueDirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvaluedirect.aspx). My guess based on the name of the resource is, this is only thrown if the code must be [CLSCompliant](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Making-Your-Code-CLS-Compliant/), but where is the body of the method? Or, put another way, how can I reflect the actual body of the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a virtual method. Presumably `Type.GetField()` is returning a *derived* type with the real implementation - try printing `info.GetType()`. (I've just tried on my box, and it showed `System.RtFieldInfo` for example.)

Answer (score 3):

Debugger shows than `testValue.GetType().GetField("MaxValue")` returns RtFieldInfo which is derived from RuntimeFieldInfo which is derived from FieldInfo. So most likely this method was overriden in one of these classes. Most likely because there are different implementation of FieldInfo for runtime types and types from reflection-only loaded assemblies

Comment: Jon was faster than light as usual, but your conclusion is equal to his ;).